# SharePoint - An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint I am getting the following when I go to my new web part page:

> Error
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator. 
>   Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

I have tried the following to get a more useful error message:

In web.config I have:

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="true">
```

and

```
<customErrors mode=“Off“/>
```

I have added the following to my web.config in my layout folder

```
<SharePoint>
    <SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false" />
</SharePoint>
```

What else can I do see a stack trace?

Comment: What was the real issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to know what exact error description is, then you need to make following changes in your SharePoint web application `web.config` file.

1. `CallStack="false"` changed to `CallStack="true"`
2. `<customErrors mode="On" />` changed to `<customErrors mode="Off" />`

Save it and do IISRESET from command line.

Open Page again then you will get exact error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the SharePoint Log files?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

> `<compilation debug="true" />`

in web.config

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your WebPart code with the Try Catch Block. Looks like some exception is left uncaught.

Answer (score 0):

it might be that the .dll that has the compiled webpart code is not copied to bin/GAC directory.
next thing I would do is to check whether the web part is in site/site collection web part gallery

hth