# Is it possible to add a CSSClass to a dynamically-created HTMLTable?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2010, html-table, htmltable-control

I am dynamically creating controls in the overridden CreateChildControls() method. I want to add a CSS class to the HTMLTable control that is housing these controls (the controls are being added to HtmlTableCells that are being created and added to HtmlTableRows, which are then added to the HTMLTable control).

The HTMLTable control does not have a CSSClass property, though, as the other Controls do. IOW, I can do this:

```
boxDeptDivName = new TextBox();
boxDeptDivName.CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input";
```

...but not this:

```
HtmlTable dynamicTable = new HtmlTable();
dynamicTable.CSSClass = "finaff-webform-table"; // <= won't compile; there is no CSSClass property for HTMLTable
```

So is it possible in some other way to add a CSSClass to a dynamically-created HTMLTable control?

### UPDATE

Mr. Lister's suggestion seems a good one; but how exactly is that done. Is it something like so:

```
HtmlTable tbl = null;
tbl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("class", "platypus-webform-table");
```

?

Comment: Don't HTML elements have a property `Attributes`? Then just add an attribute named `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are standard ASP.NET [HtmlControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s, they have a property [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a collection to which you can add new attributes as follows:

Either

```csharp
tbl.Attributes.Add("class", "platypus-webform-table");
```

or

```
tbl.Attributes["class"] = "platypus-webform-table";
```

Hope this helps!

By the way, wrt your update, you shouldn't try to access properties of an object that is `null` ;)

Comment: I don't really doubt that this is correct, but adding just that caused my Webpart to go from displaying fine (albeit without the htmtable styling) to "Web Part Error: An error has occurred." Commenting it out restores it to its prior near-pristine sublimity.

Comment: I'm not sure what goes wrong there. If that's all the error you get, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648910/sharepoint-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred) will help you get a more distinctive error description. But why did you accept my answer if it didn't help, in fact, just the opposite?

Comment: Because, like I said, I'm sure it's correct; the problem lies somewhere else, I'd be willing to wager.